# How can i pivot a table to use the column headers as values and the unique values as column headers?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following table:

| Index | First Day | Second Day | Third Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | - | Monday | Tuesday |
| 1 | Friday | Saturday | Sunday |
| 2 | Sunday | Monday | - |
| 3 | Tuesday | Wednesday | - |
| 4 | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |

What i want to do now is switch the column headers, use them as values and use the unique cell values as the new column headers. This should result in a sparse table like this:

| Index | - | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | First Day | Second Day | Third Day | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1 | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | First Day | Second Day | Third Day |
| 2 | Second Day | - | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | First Day |
| 3 | ..... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | ..... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Can someone help me accomplish this?

I tried it with:
df.pivot_table(index=df.index, columns=df.values, values=df.columns)

But that didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea, but a little more manipulation is required before the pivot:

```py
day_order = ["-", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

df.set_index("Index").stack().reset_index()\
    .pivot(index="Index", columns=0, values="level_1")\
        .reindex(day_order, axis=1)
# Out[]: 
# 0              -      Monday    Tuesday  ...      Friday    Saturday     Sunday
# Index                                    ...                                   
# 0      First Day  Second Day  Third Day  ...         NaN         NaN        NaN
# 1            NaN         NaN        NaN  ...   First Day  Second Day  Third Day
# 2      Third Day  Second Day        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN  First Day
# 3      Third Day         NaN  First Day  ...         NaN         NaN        NaN
# 4            NaN         NaN        NaN  ...  Second Day   Third Day        NaN

# [5 rows x 8 columns]
```

1. This sets the index to `Index`, then stacks, so that you have a MultiIndex with Index and the First/Second/Third Days.
2. Resetting the index puts these back as columns (so now there are 3 columns of Index, the Days and day of the week.
3. Then you can pivot with these columns.
4. Finally, sort the values into weekday order.

### EDIT:

Alternative solution for *`ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.`*

You can try using `groupby` and `unstack` instead of `pivot`, getting rid of this error:

```py
df.set_index("Index").stack().reset_index() \
    .groupby(["Index", 0])["level_1"].first().unstack() \
        .reindex(day_order, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, i get the error message ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. The problem seems to be at this part:
.pivot(index="Index", columns=0, values="level_1")

Comment: I have added an alternative solution, which should stop that error.  Let me know if that helps.